# SSH keys not working, still asking for user password

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I have read through about a dozen other similar threads and nothing in those are helping me resolve my issue.

On Windows client, using PuttyGen to set up SSH-2 RSA Keys.  And then set the putty session to use SSH/Auth/newKeys file.

On linux, i set up `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and copied the public putty key to the file.  `chmod go-r authorized_keys` and then in $home directory `chmod 700 .ssh`.  Permissions should now all be set.

On linux `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, verified `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` is properly set.  I do want to point out that `PasswordAuthentications yes` is still set, but that shouldn't matter should it, once keys are defined, ssh will use those first...or am I wrong?

As suggested in a comment, I found this in `/var/log/secure` for that users `authorized_keys` file:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file
```

Directory and file permissions are

```
drwx------ 2 userID userID 29 Apr 27 07:36 .ssh
-rw--w---- 1 userID userID 393 Apr 27 07:36 authorized_keys
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Look at `/var/log/secure` on the server side for errors and warnings as you try to connect. If you don't understand the messages please post them (as text) in your question.

Comment: And on the client side, see the debug log output, I don't know how to do that with putty though...

Comment: @roaima - thanks.  That pointed me to the following log message: `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file` for that users authorized_keys file.  Directory permissions are:  `drwx------  2 userID userID   29 Apr 27 07:36 .ssh` and file permissions are: `-rw--w---- 1 userID userID 393 Apr 27 07:36 authorized_keys` - what do I have wrong here?

Comment: Stalin Vignesh Kumar's answer below did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `authorized_keys` file should have exactly `640` permission

```
chmod 640 authorized_keys
```

should have to be exactly like below :

```
-rw-r-----.
```

Comment: that did the trick.  Thanks.  I got the `chmod go-r authorized_keys` from a tutorial.  didn't occur to me the tutorial would be wrong.

Comment: Pleasure ... yeah sometimes ... i faced this issue recently ...glad it helped...

Comment: In the tutorial that `-` should be `=` (at best). Or better `chmod u=rw,go= authorized_keys`

Comment: For the benefit of those brought here searching for a slightly different question, `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory…` under certain odd circumstances may be about the _ownership_ of the home directory, not its mode.